# How to generate a canvas app form field dynamically?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I need to build the form dynamically based on the data source data.

Here I am using excel as a data source.

[image]

In this excel I have used the 3 headers.

If I changed the field name or add the one more header, the canvas app automatically build the screen based on the data source date while I navigate to that screen

Comment: I don't understand your question, please try to rephrase it and add a code example of what you had done so helpers have a better idea. Also, use a spell check to correct you grammar. Google translate is a good source for that.

Comment: I need to build the canvas app form dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

Canvas app is actually meant for WYSIWYG app maker (low code), so there is no OOB way to achieve this dynamic control creation on load of a dynamic form layout. [Read more](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Generating-dynamic-forms-and-dynamic-controls/td-p/291457)

But anything is possible, using code logic to generate a field or show/hide and it may be messy to do in same form load. Probably you can develop a component or even PCF control to generate the control based on excel config data (control, data type and properties). You can get some idea from this [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-sem5yxaUNM&ab_channel=VirtualLearning).